# Could not find generator 'paloma:setup'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to use 'paloma' gem on Ruby (2.3.3) on Rails (5.0.0.1). I've added that gem in 'Gemfile' and its reference in 'application.js' file, after bundled, I try this according to this [link](https://libraries.io/github/howto-ruby/paloma):

```
$ rails g paloma:setup
```

But I get this message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/user/Projects/RubyRails/_Samples_/Graphs_HighCharts/config/application.rb:7)
Could not find generator 'paloma:setup'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'css:assets' or 'haml:mailer'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

And it makes no changes.
Supposedly this [link](https://libraries.io/github/howto-ruby/paloma) is a tutorial updated but in author's [link](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) doesn't mention anything about ***rails g paloma:setup/add***, so I'm confused, the author's page is not clear to me, but the tutorial of reference is, however it has this (error?) message. Both of them does not contain demos to download.

Anyone knows how to properly use this gem, and knows about a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like, the gem has not been updated for modern trains )))

Comment: What does it mean?